# Setting the default value to a select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have this list of string:

```
public static readonly List<string> LIST_ITEM_STATE = new List<string>
{
    "Brand new",
    "Never used",
    "Slightly used",
    "Used",
    "Heavily used",
    "Damaged",
    "Ruined",
    "Run for your life"
};
```

And I'm building a selectlist this way in a class:

```
public string mItemState { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mItemStateList { get; set; }

mItemStateList = new SelectList(ValueDomain.LIST_ITEM_STATE);
```

And, in my view, I render the dropdownlistfor like this:

```
Item State: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mItemState, Model.mItemStateList, String.Empty)
```

The dropdownlist works like a charm, but I've been looking for ways to set the selected value by defaul at `Brand New` while keeping the `String.Emtpty` option. How could I do that?

Comment: Please don't prefix your properties with `m`.  Not only is it a horrid hungarian-notation blowover, it is completely unnecessary because *of course* properties are members.

Comment: What would you suggest, then? Those are practices implemented in our company to easily discern between members, method parameters, and inner method variables.

Comment: If your company insists on prefixing things that are *inherently members and cannot be anything else*, then I suggest you fire the guy who wrote the standards. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to do this:

```
public static readonly List<string> LIST_ITEM_STATE = new List<string>
{
    string.Empty,
    "Brand new",
    "Never used",
    "Slightly used",
    "Used",
    "Heavily used",
    "Damaged",
    "Ruined",
    "Run for your life"
};
```

And set the selected value in the `SelectList`:

```
 mItemStateList = new SelectList(ValueDomain.LIST_ITEM_STATE, "Brand new");
```

Or make sure the value of the the property is set to the initial value you want:

```
_item.mItemState = "Brand new";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your SelectList like this:

```
mItemStateList = new SelectList(ValueDomain.LIST_ITEM_STATE, mItemState);
```